# For which $k$ can $S_n$ be generated by $\{(1\ k),(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

We know that $S_n=\left<(1\ 2),(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)\right>$, but $S_4\neq\left<(1\ 3),(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)\right>$. So the question:

> For which $k$ can $S_n$ be generated by $\{(1\ k),(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)\}$?

If $\gcd(k-1,n)=1$, then the permutation $\sigma:1\mapsto k\mapsto2k-1\mapsto\cdots\mapsto (n-1)(k-1)+1$ (mod $n$) is an $n$-cycle and equals $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)^{k-1}$. But $\{(1\ k),\sigma\}$ generates $S_n$ (since we can relabel the elements) and so the result follows. I guess that when $\gcd(k-1,n)>1$ then the conclusion is false. The problem is how do I prove that? How do I prove that something cannot generate a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if and only if $\gcd(k-1,n)=1$.

Suppose that $\gcd(k-1,n)=d>1$. Then both generators
map each set $\{k,k+d,k+2d,\ldots\}$ to itself or another
such set. They both preserve a block decomposition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$
and so not only generate a proper subgroup of $S_n$, but an
imprimitive one to boot.

The case $\gcd(k-1,n)=1$ reduces to the case $k-1=1$
by using a suitable inner automorphism of $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks! The "blocking" is somthing I thought of but I could not make the idea work, and your solution did just that.